# Is there any reason a VBA sub would stop working only on my PC?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function (bastardised from Ron DeBruin's Website) that saves the active or selected sheet as a pdf and sends it as an attachment in outlook. It still works for everyone I've given it to but lately, it is not working on my PC. I keep getting the error message as if VBA cannot save the file (due to the path being invalid or the name being used already and not wanting to overwrite)

Running on various PCs that are either running on Windows 10 or 7 (I'm on Win10) I've tried changing the save file path & the filename in the code to something more simple and I still have the same issues. I tried the file on another machine running windows 10 and had no issues. I've also tried checking Microsoft Add-Ins and everything is fine.

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
Sub RDB_Worksheet_Or_Worksheets_To_PDF_And_Create_Mail()
    Dim FileName As String

    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "There is more than one sheet selected," & vbNewLine & _
               "be aware that every selected sheet will be published"
    End If

    'Call the function with the correct arguments
    'Tip: You can also use Sheets("YourSheetName") instead of ActiveSheet in the code(sheet does not have to be active then)

    FileName = RDB_Create_PDF(Source:=ActiveSheet, _
                              FixedFilePathName:="C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\Container Shipment Reports\" & (Range("G4").Value) & ".pdf", _
                              OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, _
                              OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)

    'For a fixed file name use this in the FixedFilePathName argument
    'FixedFilePathName:="C:\Users\Ron\Test\YourPdfFile.pdf"


    If FileName <> "" Then
        RDB_Mail_PDF_Outlook FileNamePDF:=FileName, _
                             StrTo:="XXXXXX.XXXXXXX@XXXXX.com.au", _
                             StrCC:="XXXXXX.XXXXXXX@XXXXX.com.au; XXXXXX.XXXXXXX@XXXXX.com.au", _
                             StrBCC:="", _
                             StrSubject:="Container Shipment Report " & (Range("G4").Value) & ".", _
                             Signature:=True, _
                             Send:=False, _
                             StrBody:="<body>Hello,</body><br>" & _
                                      "<body>Please see the attached Container Shipment Report# " & (Range("G4").Value) & " from " & (Range("E4").Value) & "." & _
                                      "<br><br>" & "Thank you.</body>"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not possible to create the PDF, possible reasons:" & vbNewLine & _
               "Microsoft Add-in is not installed" & vbNewLine & _
               "You Canceled the GetSaveAsFilename dialog" & vbNewLine & _
               "The path to Save the file in arg 2 is not correct" & vbNewLine & _
               "You didn't want to overwrite the existing PDF if it exists"

End If

Application.Quit

End Sub
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

This should convert to PDF, attach to an email, send the email and then close Excel. At the moment I am just getting the MsgBox response from the code, "Not possible to create PDF, possible reasons: etc".
(there is also a function to stop the excel file saving as it is meant to be a blank template.) As I said this seems to be an issue only on my machine but as it works on other computers I'm thinking there's no issue with the code.

Comment: Without seeing what `RDB_Create_PDF` does it's hard to debug further.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2010/ee834871(v%3Doffice.11)   Try debugging that function and find out why the return value is an empty string.  Doesn't look like the issue is with the code you posted.

Comment: Something that strikes me is the `Environ("Username")` or perhaps the complete line `FixedFilePathName:="C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\Container Shipment Reports\" & (Range("G4").Value) & ".pdf"` is that a valid path? `deubg.print FixedFilePathName:="C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\Container Shipment Reports\"` and see if you can paste it in explorer without problems? Why is `... & (Range("G4").Value) & ".pdf"` enclosed in `()`?

Comment: Have you tried running the code with VBA Error Trapping set to "Break on All Errors" so that you see where the code fails? Finding out where it isn't working is key to solving the problem.

Comment: Do not use `"C:\Users\" & Environ("Username")`. Use `Environ("UserProfile")`. The user folder is not always on C:, and its name is not always identically to the username.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As I said, I'm not having trouble with the code on other machines and it used to work fine on my PC. I just don't know what could have changed to make this stop working. I will try running the debugger and maybe it will let me know what's happening.

Comment: I am having no luck with this at all. The form works on other people's PCs but not mine where it was created. My computer died and was replaced and the new pc worked fine. Now the new PC is doing the same thing.